# Error:(4, 32) error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist

Tags: android, android-camera

while using the camera2 Android to build a camera preview into TectureView  api ,I got this error :

> Error:(4, 32) error: package android.hardware.camera2 does not exist

I target SDK 22 with minimum SDK 14.

My device os is Android 4.4

Comment: The minimum for camera2 is API 21, Android 5.0. It doesn't matter what you target, it matters what your minimum is set to.

Answer (score 4):

Change `compileSdkVersion 17` to `minimum 21` (recommended 23) in `build.gradle` file of the OpenCV module.
Because `android.hardware.camera2` was added in API 21.